# Pass params like variable to evaluate in casperjs and login into site

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, casperjs, web-crawler

I'm writing a python script that pass username and password like params to my casperjs script, describe below. But I don't know why a receive the error:

```
CasperError: casper.test property is only available using the `casperjs test` command
     C:/casperjs/modules/casper.js:179
```

Can someone help me about this issue?

CasperJS.py:

```
import os
import subprocess

# PATH to files
casperjs = 'c:\casperjs\bin\casperjs.exe'
app_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
script = os.path.join(app_root, 'test2.js')

#  Request username and password
username = raw_input("Usuario:")
password = raw_input("Senha:")

# Username and password like
auth = [username, password] 

# Execute process casperjs via python
subprocess.Popen(['casperjs', script, auth[0], auth[1]], shell=True)
```

CasperJS.js:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScript: ['jquery.min.js'],
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
    // Disable load images
    pageSettings: {
    loadImages: true
    }
});

# variables
var url = 'http://minha.oi.com.br';
var username = casper.echo(casper.cli.raw.get(0));
var password = casper.echo(casper.cli.raw.get(1)); 

# start casperjs
casper.start(url);

# Try login on the website
casper.thenEvaluate(function(usuario, senha) {
document.querySelector('input#Ecom_User_ID').setAttribute('value', usuario);
document.querySelector('input#Ecom_Password').setAttribute('value', password);

}, { usuario: username, senha: password });

# Check the current URL
casper.then(function() {
        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
});
casper.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was an old version of phantomjs that did not work properly with casperjs. The issues below provide corrections to the code in the question.

---

Your scripts have multiple issues

- You can't `echo` something and try to assign the value in your casperjs script. So change those two lines to:

  ```js
  casper.echo(casper.cli.raw.get(0));
  casper.echo(casper.cli.raw.get(1));

  var username = casper.cli.raw.get(0);
  var password = casper.cli.raw.get(1);
  ```
- In the same script: Your comments are python comments and not js comments, so change `#` to `//`
- In casper: You should actually select the correct input fields:

  ```
  document.querySelector('input[name="Ecom_User_ID"]').setAttribute('value', usuario);
  document.querySelector('input[name="Ecom_Password"]').setAttribute('value', senha);
  ```

  Or even use a function that is provided by casperjs (replacing the complete `thenEvaluate` call):

  ```js
  this.fillSelectors("form[name='IDPLogin']", {
      'input[name="Ecom_User_ID"]': username,
      'input[name="Ecom_Password"]': password
  });
  ```
- you may change the `thenEvaluate` call to:

  ```js
  casper.thenEvaluate(function(usuario, senha) {
      // setAttribute here like above
  }, username, password);
  ```
- In your python script you don't actually use the `casperjs` variable, but that's fine since you assume that it is in PATH.

If the error persists or a new one comes up, try updating to a *newer* version of phantomjs.

---

The resulting code might look like this:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();

// variables
var url = 'http://minha.oi.com.br';
var username = casper.cli.raw.get(0);
var password = casper.cli.raw.get(1);

// start casperjs
casper.start(url);

// Try login on the website
casper.then(function(){
    this.fillSelectors("form[name='IDPLogin']", {
        'input[name="Ecom_User_ID"]': username,
        'input[name="Ecom_Password"]': password
    }, true);
    // this also sents the form
});

// Check the current URL
casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Hi, Artjom B, I change my script casperjs and remove the casper.echo, but i continuous without login to the web site.
My casperjs version is 1.1.0-beta3 and phantomjs 1.9.1

Comment: @RodrigoAndrade see the added third point. Your selector is wrong

Comment: Hi, @Artjom B,
I try both samples and I continuous cant login into the website. I dont know if this true, but i think the value of the variables usuario and password didnt been send to inputs.

Comment: @RodrigoAndrade Try using the other syntax for the `thenEvaluate` call. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hi, @Artjom B, when a change my script like you mentioned i receive the error:
CasperError: casper.test property is only available using the `casperjs test` command  C:/casperjs/modules/casper.js:179
I'm using Eclipe to developer my script, my goal is create a form with two fields where the user will type email and password perform login and retrieve same informations.

Comment: @RodrigoAndrade You should update your phantomjs. The current version is 1.9.7. I can't even run casperjs with such an old phantomjs. Also beware that you mixed up some variables. If you want to login, then you need to click the login button after filling out the fields.

Comment: Hi @Artjom B, after update the version of phantomjs I can fill the form login.
Thank you very much for you assitance.